# Peer not Authenticated when connecting to url

Tags: java, authentication

Forgive my ignorance, I really have no idea what I am doing as this is my first web program.  I know that the server I am trying to access does not require verification, as someone helped me edit the web.xml file which removed the Authentication filter.  However, when trying to connect to the url I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:397)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:126)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:437)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
    at ParseTesting.AccessURL.main(AccessURL.java:74)
```

If you have any thoughts, please pass them my way.  Here is the source:

```
package ParseTesting;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;


public class AccessURL {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //final String server = "https://myurl.edited.for.web.post";
        final String username = "admin";
        final String password = "password";


        DefaultHttpClient client =  new DefaultHttpClient();


        HttpGet  httpget = new HttpGet(server);

        String authString = "admin:dangerous";
        System.out.println("auth string: " + authString);
        byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
        String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
        System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);

        httpget.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);
        System.out.println(response);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String str = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The remote host's SSL certificate is not verifiable to a known CA root using the CA certificates available to your Java client.  If the remote host is using a self-signed certificate, you will need to add the private CA certificate to your Java client's keystore.  If it's a commercial certificate, add the appropriate root CA certificate to the keystore.